# ModelMapper fail to convert java.util.list to java.util.list on DeleteMapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

good day everyone,

i have this project where i use the ModelMapper to mat my entities to DTOs and vise-versa, and also have a class with @ElementCollection relation.
the mapper seems to work fine for all other methods and it just output the entity as i want, however when it comes to delete mapping i get the following error printed along with a 500 http status. here's the error:

> "ModelMapper mapping errors:\r\n\r\n1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.CollectionConverter@ddb7bc7 failed to convert java.util.List to java.util.List.\r\n\r\n1 error"

here is code:

the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "quiz_engines")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
    value = {"lastModified"},
    allowGetters = true
)
public class Engine implements Model {

@Id
@Column(name = "engine_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false, targetEntity = com.QCMGenerator.QCMGenerator.Model.Test.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "test_id", referencedColumnName = "test_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
@JsonIgnore
private Test test;

@Column(name = "quiz_name", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private String name;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "last_modified", nullable = false)
@LastModifiedDate
private Date lastModified;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "engine_constraints", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "engine_id"))
private List<EngineConstraint> constraints;

public Engine() {
}

public Engine(@NotNull String name, List<EngineConstraint> constraints) {
    this.name = name;
    this.constraints = constraints;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Test getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(Test test) {
    this.test = test;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Date getLastModified() {
    return lastModified;
}

public void setLastModified(Date lastModified) {
    this.lastModified = lastModified;
}

public List<EngineConstraint> getConstraints() {
    return constraints;
}

public void setConstraints(List<EngineConstraint> constraints) {
    this.constraints = constraints;
}
}
```

the DTO class:

```
public class EngineDTO implements ModelDTO {

private Long id;

@JsonIgnore
private TestDTO test;

private String name;

private Date lastModified;

private List<EngineConstraint> constraints;

public EngineDTO() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public TestDTO getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(TestDTO test) {
    this.test = test;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Date getLastModified() {
    return lastModified;
}

public void setLastModified(Date lastModified) {
    this.lastModified = lastModified;
}

public List<EngineConstraint> getConstraints() {
    return constraints;
}

public void setConstraints(List<EngineConstraint> constraints) {
    this.constraints = constraints;
}
}
```

the Delete Controller:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{engineID}")
public ResponseEntity<NonPaginatedResponse> deleteEngine(
        @PathVariable(value = "testID") Long testID,
        @PathVariable(value = "engineID") Long engineID
){
    if(!testRepo.existsById(testID)){
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("No test with the ID '"+testID+"' was found...");
    }

    return engineRepo.findById(engineID).map(engineFound -> {
                engineRepo.delete(engineFound);
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(
                        ResponseBodyBuilder.getSingleResponse(
                                convertToDTO(engineFound),
                                new ModelDTO[]{ convertToDTO(testRepo.findById(testID).get()) },
                                "delete"
                        )
                );
            }
    ).orElseThrow(
            () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("No Engine with the ID '"+engineID+"' was found...")
    );
}
```

hope you guys can help with this one, thank for your time everyone and have a good day.

Comment: try to adding ignoreUnknown = true in @JsonIgnoreProperties,

Comment: it didn't work, the problem is with the mapper, which i have no idea why it's behaving this way

Comment: for some reason the operation didn't work because i deleted the object from the database, i guess i don't understand orms as well as i thought